# ftp_connect() is not working in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, connection

My ftp_connect() is not working what is done is as follow:

input:

```
    $file = 'COPYING.txt';
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect("74.3.171.67");
var_dump($conn_id);
```

output:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: Could you provide additional information, any errors, settings, what is it your connecting to? etc

Comment: @segarci thank you for reply. i have checked error log no errors.

Comment: @Scriptable i have so much to do only if this works. i need to connect it first. please help

Comment: Can you connect to the server using an FTP client such as FileZilla?

Comment: @Scriptable yes i can connect it with filezilla and also with winscp.

Comment: you probably need to specify connection type, port, credentials etc

Comment: @Scriptable 

$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect("74.3.171.67",22); 
var_dump($conn_id);

i tried this but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

If the output if false, it means the ftp connect has failed. This is either due to the server not accepting connections, the server not running or the PHP server being unable to connect to it.

I'd suggest trying to connect to the ftp server via an ftp client to verify the FTP server is up and running correctly. If it is, the problem is your server cannot reach it.

Comment: It is running on the PHP server only. if now i just tried to put the port as follows:

$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect("74.3.171.67",22);
var_dump($conn_id);

it is loading and only loading

Comment: By that do you mean that the FTP is running on the same server as the PHP? If so, why not just use localhost as the IP?

Comment: $conn_id = ftp_connect('127.0.0.1');
var_dump($conn_id);


still not working. have you ever tried if so then please give me some code.

Comment: Have I coded ftp connections in PHP? Yes. What is the port of your ftp server? The default (21)?